# Android App crashes every second time when i call fragment from activity?

Tags: java, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have created a simple main fragment page with a button that calls the activity class layout and on reaching activty class ,that acitivity class call back fragment class layout on button click .
Below is the simple fragment class with a simple button that calls activity class and it works without any issue. But once Acitiviy page is opened , on clicking button to go back to fragment layout ,it crash the app every second time i click that button. any help would be highly appreciated.

with below error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b007d
> (org.pjsip.pjsua2:id/container01) for fragment fragment_login{1bd38c1
> (5a612956-fc18-4272-8230-f79e71fed06a) id=0x7f0b007d}
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
> at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)

```
public class fragment_login extends Fragment  {

    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    public int Register=0;


    public fragment_login() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

  
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static fragment_login newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        fragment_login fragment = new fragment_login();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        send = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        return v;

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            // i am calling Mainactivity3 class here ,which takes me to activity layout and it works 
            }
        });
    }
```

// below is the activity class which get called on clicking button from fragment class and here i am  trying to call back fragment class , but it crash every second time i click this button.

```
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);


        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

// below code to get back to fragment layout works ony once after fresh loading the app and it crash every second time i click this button.

```
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container01,new fragment_login()).commit();


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Id 'container01' in your MainActivity XML to add fragment into container.

**MainActivity XML**

```
<!--Container for Fragments-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contFragments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```